# Navigate to specific tab in PhpStorm (CMD-1 / SUPER-1)

Tags: phpstorm, keyboard-shortcuts

In Google Chrome and Atom (and probably also in other programs), it's possible to 'Go to tab # 1' by pressing <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> (for Mac) or <kbd>SUPER</kbd> + <kbd>1</kbd> (for Windows). I love that feature more than I love my mother, - but I can't find anyone else requesting a way to set it up in PhpStorm (for some reason).

I know that I can navigate to other tabs using the Switcher or pressing <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd> or <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd>. I have read all of this page: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2017.1/navigating-between-editor-tabs.html - without any luck.

I've also gone through the Keymap in the settings, looking for a way to set it up - but I can't find a way. In the Keymap - there is no actions called: 'Go to tab # 1' nor 'Go to tab # $var'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such built-in functionality available.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-68324 -- follow this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified on any progress.

---

But you may use **GoToTabs plugin** for such browser-like tab navigation.

Comment: The GoToTabs Plugin did the job. As the plugin states, then the shortcuts has to be assigned manually - but that's easily done.