# How to switch between tabs in PhpStorm?

Tags: phpstorm, keyboard-shortcuts

How do you switch between tabs in the PhpStorm editor with a Danish keyboard layout? This doesn't work: ⇧⌘]

Comment: Are you talking about Switcher (something like `Alt+Tab` on Windows) -- should be `Ctrl+Tab`; ... or just switching to editor tab that is on the Left/Right to the current one (should be `Alt+Left/Right` AFAIK). P.S. Not a Mac user here.

Comment: If you have for example 5 tabs, and the third one open. How do you switch to tab number 2 (or 4)?
I'm using MacOS with Danish keyboard layout.

Comment: if ` ⇧⌘]` doesn't work for you, you can assign a different shortcut to **Main menu | Window | Editor Tabs | Select Next Tab** action in **Preferences | Keymap**

Comment: @allanth If you want to select *specific tab number* -- you have to use custom plugin for that  see https://stackoverflow.com/a/43923283/783119. If you need to select Left/Right tab from the current one -- see what Lena have said (use that action (shortcut) or assign another shortcut if default does not work)

Comment: @lena's answer should be the best!

Comment: Actually <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>cm</kbd> + left/right works. There's a strange warning like sound.

Answer (score 10):

**Press** <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Right</kbd>  **or** <kbd>Alt</kbd>+ <kbd>Left</kbd>

**Press** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to use the Switcher.